# Autofac EnableInterfaceInterceptors Error

Tags: autofac, castle-dynamicproxy

We updating to Autofac 2.4.4 after moving up to MVC3 and are receiving an exception when we include `EnableInterfaceInterceptors` on our registration.  The exception does not appear until `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISite>()` is called.

Exception:

```
Could not load type 'System.Func`2' from assembly 'App.AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy2, Version=2.4.4.705, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Registration:

```
builder.RegisterType<SendEmailTask>().As<ITask>().InstancePerDependency().EnableInterfaceInterceptors();
```

Note: In order to deal with conflicts in the different versions of Castle we performed an ILMerge on `AutofacContrib.DynamicProxy2.dll` and `Castle.Core.dll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a problem with the IL merge - rather than merging, have you tried assembly binding redirects?

Comment: I was not able to get it to compile.  SlimReaderWriterLock is not in latest version of Castle.Core so bindingRedirect failed.

Comment: I ended up having to upgrade some other components in order to get it working.